# How to know which index a child was added to an ordered FirebaseQuery

Tags: swift, firebase

Using Firebase and Swift SDK

I just started with Firebase and wanted to display a list of Conversations ordered by last_update. The following query works fine :

```
let query = Database.database().reference().child("chat").child("channels").queryOrdered(byChild: "last_update")

query.observe(DataEventType.childAdded) { (snapshot: DataSnapshot) in
    if let value = snapshot.value as? [String: Any?] {
        log.debug("added channel: \(snapshot.key) : \(value)")
        //add object to array, insertRow in tableview
    }
}
```

The first time my view is loaded, each item arrives in the correct order specified by the query, so the display is ok. But if I create a new channel, it does appear at the end of the tableview, because I just add it at the end of the array and just call insertRow on my table view. My question is : is there any mecanism that give us the new inserted position of the DataSnapshot ?

Same question for DataEventType.childMoved : we get to know that a snapshot has moved, but how to know where it has moved ??

Comment: I guess you can't know since you get no information about adding / moving back with the snapshot. What you could do is every time .childAdded .childMoved gets called, sort the results by your property and reload tableview.

Comment: this is a solution but it seems too much : ordering as already been performed by the query, I should not have to do it again. And it also prevent me from doing fine grained update on the table view (with moving/inserting animations)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally end up using FirebaseUI, especially the submodule FirebaseDatabaseUI (see the github repo [here](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-iOS/tree/master/FirebaseDatabaseUI))
They provide a FUITableViewDataSource, you just create a query and pass it to it, it will handle everything like sorting etc. I also used FUIArray, which is simply an array backed by a query, with a delegate for added / deleted / moved / update events (and proper indexes).